# Incoming form POST gets unexpected content type

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, content-type

When submitting a `Post` request to a `WebApi` controller, with the content type set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the Content property of the request is an instance of `StreamContent`. There is a content type for `FormUrlEncodedContent` which would seem to be more appropriate in the circumstances.

1. Is there anything else I need to specify in order to receive the content as the expected type?
2. If not, is there a specific reason that `WebApi` provides this more generic content type?

**Edit**

To clarify, I'm not concerned with the response type, I'm interested to know why `WebApi` populates the *incoming* content type as an instance of `StreamContent` rather than `FormUrlEncodedContent`

Comment: return type? json,xml? `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` just post format

Comment: Is the return type relevant? this is the content type of the request, ive not returned anything at this point

Comment: i think question is not clear or confusing..any api will return wither XML or JSON

Comment: Can you show your code and explain _what_ you post? Is it a combination of form fields and files?